# Verify that $d:C^1\to F$ where $d(f)=f'$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on this problem from my linear algebra class lecture notes. I know how to show that a transformation is linear, but I am unsure what the vector spaces mean. I think that $C^1$ is the set of all continuous functions that have continuous first derivatives, and it is being mapped to a field. From my understanding, a field consists of scalars. Does this mean that this linear transformation only maps functions where the first derivative is a scalar?

Comment: I think it's well known that $(\lambda f+g)'=\lambda f'+g'$ for all $f\in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ and all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, so the result should be rather straightforward...

Comment: I'm not sure what the source of your question is, so you should check there to figure out what $F$ is. However, it might mean $F(\mathbb{R})$, which is just the set of functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $df=f’,$ then $F$ is not a field,  since $f’$ is a function, not a scalar.

Comment: In particular, $F$ must include all functions on the domain which have an anti-derivative. It could include other functions, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ for some integer $n > 0$. Then we can define
$$F(B) = \{ f \mid f:B \to \Bbb R\text{ is a function}\}$$
If $a,b \in \Bbb R$, and $f, g \in F(B)$, then we can define the function
$$af + bg : B \to \Bbb R : t \mapsto af(t) + bg(t)$$

which makes $F(B)$ a vector space over the scalar field $\Bbb R$.

If $B$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, then we can define inductively
$$\begin{align}C^0(B) &= \{f \in F(B) \mid f \text{ is continuous}\}\\
C^k(B) &= \{f \in F(B) \mid  \text{ all partial derivatives of }f\text{ exist and are in }C^{k-1}(B)\}\end{align}$$

For any $k \ge 0; a,b \in \Bbb R$ if $f, g \in C^k(B)$ then $af + bg \in C^k(B)$. So each of the $C^k(B)$ are vector subspaces of $F$. And for all $k, C^{k+1}(B) \subset C^k(B)$.

In your problem, apparently the domain $B$ is being taken as known, so they didn't bother to write it explicitly in the notation.

You can extend the notation to use other codomains than $\Bbb R$, and to use $\Bbb C$ as the field. But that is another discussion.